# How to send a "proper" POST request to an API

Tags: php, post, curl

I am currently trying to send a POST request to an API, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

What I need to do is send a POST request like described here:

```
POST /v2/sessions HTTP/1.1
Host: api.etilbudsavis.dk
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{
  "api_key": "YOUR_APP_KEY"
}
```

And this is one of the ways i've tried to handle it using curl library:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://api.etilbudsavis.dk/v2/sessions");

$postData = array(
        'api_key' => '{'.$api_key.'}'
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Host: localhost",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Origin: localhost"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if($response === FALSE){
    echo 'Error<br>';
}


$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
print_r($responseData);

print_r(curl_error($curl));
```

My output in the browser:

```
Error 
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `print_r( curl_error($curl) );` give? You *may* also want to have `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in your `curl_setopt_array()` for later use.

Comment: i gave me nothing before (because of the die('Error')), but i've updated the question now and written what the print_r is returning.

Comment: Try adding `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE` in your `curl_setopt_array()` - this introduces some security risks...

Comment: Check-out the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. You should be using this rather than disabling SSL_VERIFYPEER. Also `http_build_query()` is probably what you're looking for rather than `json_encode()` when sending your POST data.

Comment: Ahh cool thanks a lot! CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE solved the problem. using the CURLOPT_CAINFO gave me the following message: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: none

Comment: @user68621 `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` **shouldn't** be used on production! I was wrong to suggest it. Follow Jaspers' advice

Comment: @user68621 You need to set the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option to the absolute path of a PEM (or like) file.

Comment: the Api that im using requires that I send json encoded data. I can't seem to get my request working using the CURLOPT_CAINFO. 
Anyways, the data that i'm receiving is not sensitive at all and is planned to be public available, so it doesn't matter if anyone gets a hold of it on the midway. But i am still curious about why I can't get it to work with CURLOPT_CAINFO .

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd personally recommend using a request library, such as the wonderful [Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests). You can add it via Composer!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a bogus `Host:` header.

This header is intended to tell a server hosting multiple virtual hosts on a single IP address which vhost the request is intended for. Curl will set this header for you *automatically* and should only be manually overridden if you're trying to circumvent DNS for development/testing of the *destination* machine.